# Change the text of UILabel on UITableviewCell without the dequeue mechanism

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i was having troubles using the dequeue mechanism in my table view, so i decide to load all the cells at once. 
Well i have a custom cell with a label on it.
What happens is that all the cells are loaded but there is no information on the label.
Here is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

MyCell *cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Prototipo *prototipo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.lblIdentificador.text = [prototipo.identificador stringValue];


return cell;
```

}

Thank you guys.

Comment: More than likely you will eventually take a performance hit loading all the cells at once and be forced to revert back to dequeuing the cells. Why don't you ask how to fix the dequeuing instead of asking how to load all of the cells? Just curious...

Comment: i just tried to simplify my question. i have the same issue in another scenario, i did some research and the problem the cause of the problem is the dequeue, that's why i want to load the cell at once.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to load all the cells at once?

Comment: Sure. The problem is that a have a uiTextField on the cell and when i scroll the table the value the i have typed on the textfield goes to another cell.

Comment: You need to fix the issue that is preventing you from using the normal table view cell loading mechanism. Apple spent an enormous number of hours finding the most efficient way to render a table so that the user experience is not bad. Trying to get around this is a terrible idea, and will cause you far more pain than just fixing your code for the text view.

Comment: I would like a lot to do that. But i don't know how. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you were having problems figuring out how to use the cell reuse mechanism, you figure out that problem before you move forward. UITableViews are one of the core building blocks of iOS and uses most the core concepts that are essential to development.

That said, I will still attempt to help you. Based upon your code, I expect your `prototipo` object is `nil`. Unlike other languages where performing an operation on `null` is an error, calling a selector on `nil` is not an error.

You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint and walking through your code.

Comment: It is not nil. All the cells are loaded but there is no information on the label.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Prototipo *prototipo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblIdentificador.text = [prototipo.identificador stringValue];
return cell;
```

You will be good to go

**Notice**: you must make sure `prototipo` is not a `nil`, you can use `NSLog` to double check the return value

Comment: It works. But i don't wanna to use the [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; I want to load all the cells at once.

Comment: the data comes from a table. So the number of cells can change. Can i use static cells in this conditions ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Instead of using static cellIndentifier "MyCell". Name your cell identifier according to your datasource. e.g: `NSString *cellIdentifier = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPatch.row]`. This should work because each cell will have its own identifier

Comment: I've just tried that to. But the result is the same, all cells loaded but no information on the label.